# Adding License Agreement in RPM package

Tags: package, licensing, rpm

Is it possbile to add License agreement in the RPM package?
When user installs the RPM, it should prompt to accept the user license agreement.

Comment: Similar query I have asked for Solaris and Colin's suggestion is working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377074/adding-user-license-agreement-in-solaris-package

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bad idea for both technical and user-interface reasons.

Not only because there may be no display during install, but also because there may be no *user* during installation or even first run, or the mechanism for extracting the rpm file may simply not support any method to display text or accept input.

Essentially, if you *have* to do this, the least worst way is to do Ignacio suggests, which is what Sun do, and create a RPM file with no such restriction, then put it inside a self-extracting binary which displays the license, prompts the user and then unwraps the RPM.  In the spirit of ruining the user experience, you will also require a set of instructions like these created by Sun: [JRE RPM Installation for Linux](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-install-linux-rpm.html).

The correct way of doing this of course is to use the `License` field and include a file as `%doc` which contains your licensing terms.  This does away with the 'click-through' step, which maybe unacceptable to your lawyers, although it is widely considered to be unenforceable anyway.

This is the section of the RPM guidelines which addresses such things:

> The package may not use interactive
> pre-install, post-install,
> pre-uninstall, or post-uninstall
> scripts. The user must not be prompted
> at anytime during the install,
> upgrade, or removal — Everything must
> be completely automated. ([RPM Guidelines, Fedora Project](https://web.archive.org/web/20090803110914/http://docs.fedoraproject.org:80/developers-guide/s1-rpm-guidelines.html))

Remember, the first impression your user will get of your product could be either this:
[image: Software Installer]
<sub>(source: [virtuatopia.com](https://www.virtuatopia.com/images/e/e1/Virtualbox_software_installer.jpg))</sub>

or this:

[image: Netbeans-03.png]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm1.static.flickr.com/243/514585114_a7822b0272.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for such a detail explanation.
> This is a bad idea for both technical and user-interface reasons.
I know its bad idea, just wanted to get the expert views if we have to do it anyhow.

Comment: Any suggestions as to where to learn how to put a RPM "inside a self-extracting binary which [does stuff] then unwraps the RPM"?  Any pointers / suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that; there's no guarantee that the package will be installed when there's even a display to *show* the license agreement. Put it in a self-extracting archive that shows the agreement on execute.

Comment: Another thing, how can we contorl the display of License agreement to the screen size? i dont want to simply cat the license file text and suer has to scroll up and see. Is it possible through shell script?

Comment: Look for the following things, in order: `$PAGER`, the presence of `less`, the presence of `more`.