# spec file with license agreement

Tags: rpm

I want to offer Oracle JDK on my repository server as depedency for my other packages. According to the Oracle License, to be able to redistribute the software, a user has to agree to the license before downloading. 
Now I found already a few questions like this here, but either they said it's not possible or I shall not do it or if, then I would need to build a shell script around it.

But at least for the rpm installers, I found examples like this

```
sudo apt-get install curl --assume-yes
```

and

```
zypper patch --auto-agree-with-licenses
```

So I guess there must be a way to integrate it in RPM, at least to show it before installing. Or is the way to go really a shell script around and these installer tools will just throw a yes on whatever comes up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding License Agreement in RPM package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132828/adding-license-agreement-in-rpm-package)

Comment: Yes, I saw that question/Answer as well, but it still does not answer my question. Because the apt-get and zypper rpm install tools have a auto-agree flags. So it must be considered by them, that there are license agreement inside a rpm that demand a respsonse by a user.

Comment: The description for `apt-get` suggests that it's used only for agreeing about things that the tool controls (such as accepting gpg keys).  It's not an rpm tool anyway.  For `zypper`, the [documentation](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage_11.3#Auto-agree_with_licenses) is a start, but reading the source-rpms would tell you what it does.

Answer (score 0):

export ACCEPT_EULA='y' && rpm -ivh msodbcsql17-17.9.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm

If in a Dockerfile, then

RUN export ACCEPT_EULA='y' && rpm -ivh msodbcsql17-17.9.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm